# In Reactjs, How to change the default css in the react-select?

Tags: reactjs, api

---How to change the Default css in the page?

<Select className="flex-container"

```
          //key={i}
          //styles={customStyles}
          placeholder={name}
          //multi={true}
          multiple={true}
         
          options={this.state[name].options}
          
          
          onChange={this.onSelectChange.bind(this, name)}

        />
```

We need to change the default class in the page ? So , We need to remove existing class in the page?

Comment: We are using the react-select in reactjs page.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question, but I think you can just change the className to the name of the class you want to use. Honestly, it is very difficult to decipher what you are trying to say.